# Match between two row data

Tags: mysql, sql, match

I want to select match count from result where the match count is exact int on a date.

```
date        id_event    id_timewindows      max_hits
2014-12-16  1           1,2,3               2
2014-12-16  2           2,3,4               2
2014-12-16  3           4                   2
2014-12-16  4           5,6                 2
2014-12-16  5           7,8                 2
2014-12-16  6           9                   2
```

The result what i want is:

```
date        id_event    id_timewindows      max_hits
2014-12-16  1           2,3                 2
2014-12-16  2           2,3                 2
```

Have anybody idea, how to do it in MySQL?

### **UPDATE:**

So i have to explain more. The `id_timewindows` is not a `string` attribute, the first one is a result of a view which `grouped by id_events` and `one id_event has multiple id_timewindow`.

View result before grouped:

```
date        id_event    id_timewindow       begin       end         max_rooms
2014-12-16  1           1                   06:00:00    07:00:00    2
2014-12-16  1           2                   07:00:00    08:00:00    2
2014-12-16  1           3                   08:00:00    09:00:00    2
2014-12-16  2           2                   07:00:00    08:00:00    2
2014-12-16  2           3                   08:00:00    09:00:00    2
2014-12-16  2           4                   09:00:00    10:00:00    2
2014-12-16  3           4                   09:00:00    10:00:00    2
2014-12-16  4           6                   11:00:00    12:00:00    2
2014-12-16  4           5                   10:00:00    11:00:00    2
2014-12-16  5           7                   12:00:00    13:00:00    2
2014-12-16  5           8                   13:00:00    14:00:00    2
2014-12-16  6           9                   14:00:00    15:00:00    2
```

I use `GROUP BY id_event` and the `id_timewindows` is `group_concat(id_timewindow SEPARATOR ',')`

Comment: post the table definition

Comment: I do not understand how you get your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
SELECT 
   date,
   id_timewindow,
   max_rooms,
   COUNT(concat(date, id_timewindow)) as counter

FROM `timewindows_reserved`
GROUP BY
   date, id_timewindow

HAVING counter < max_rooms
```

That will result what inverse what i want and i can use it.

```
date        id_timewindow     max_hits
2014-12-16  1                 2
2014-12-16  4                 2
2014-12-16  5                 2
2014-12-16  6                 2
2014-12-16  7                 2
2014-12-16  8                 2
2014-12-16  9                 2
```

If I group by date and make a LIST from the `id_timewindow` then i can recevie the same result as what I wanted, but in inverse logic. Not a reserved timewindows rather the free timewindows. If I reverse this then I  can get the result:

```
SELECT 
   date,
   id_event,
   GROUP_CONCAT(id_timewindow SEPARATOR ','),
   max_rooms,
   COUNT(concat(date, id_timewindow)) as counter

FROM `table`
GROUP BY
   date, id_timewindow

HAVING counter >= max_rooms
```